# Always getting error code in JMeter for missing Alias in certificate

Tags: ssl, testing, jmeter, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a problem when loading a client-side certificate using Jmeter. I tried everything including editing system.properties file, with these lines:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 or jks  
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/jsk keystore or .p12 certificate
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your certificate or keystore password
```

Then importing certificate manually through SSL manager and manually typing password, nothing works.

I always have this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No certificate found for alias:'mykey'
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:404)
    at .....
```

Alias is there, as print from certificate is showing:
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: mykey
Creation date: Sep 27, 2019
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

What could be causing Jmeter to fail reading the certificate? Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

The approach with *system.properties* file works fine, just make sure to restart JMeter to pick the changes up.

Another option is passing the properties via -D command line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=your.keystore.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret
```

Replace `your.keystore.p12` and `secret` with the full or relative path to your .p12 keystore and the actual password accordingly.

More information:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/)

Comment: Thank you for answer. However everything you wrote has been tried and error is still the same. Here is error from log: 2019-10-03 11:04:57,480 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2019-10-03 11:04:57,668 ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found
java.io.IOException: No key(s) found

Comment: Configurations should be correct.
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/Users/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/MyCard2.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword

Any idea what else could be the issue ?

Comment: Check `https.keyStoreStartIndex ` and `https.keyStoreEndIndex` properties, maybe you're setting indices to the range above 1 so the key cannot be found. You could add the next line to *system.properties* file `javax.net.debug=ssl` and look for suspicious entries in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and in the [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) files.